# Number of elements in the orbit

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

$X$ is the set $\{1,2,\ldots,11\}$ and $G$ is the cyclic group $\{p^n: n\in \mathbb Z\}$ generated by the permuation
$$p=(7\;2\;9)(11\;5\;4\;8\;6\;10)(1)(3),$$ of $X$.

Determine the number of elements in

1. the orbit $G10$,
2. the fixed-point subgroup $G_{10}$ and
3. the group $G$.

Remember that the orbit $Gx$ of $x$ is the set $\{f(x)\,:\, f\in G\}$ and that the fixed-point subgroup $G_x$ of $x$ is $\{f\in G\,:\, f(x)=x\}$ and that it is a simple relation between the number of elements in these sets.

If i understand correctly in part $1.$ i should calculate ${\left( {(7\,\,2\,\,9)(1\,\,1\,\,5\,\,4\,\,8\,\,6\,\,1\,\,0)(1)(3)} \right)^{10}}$? I have no idea how to calculate the tenth power of the product of cycles...Also i don't understand what is required in parts $2$ and $3$...

Could someone provide some hints please?

Comment: I don't think you understood part 1 correctly.  The group $G$ acts on the set $X$.  The orbit $Gx$ is the set of all images of $x$ acted upon by the permutations in $G$.  The permutations in $G$ are all powers of $p$, and "10" here (in part 1) is a point in $X$, not a specific power of $p$.

Comment: @hardmath and how to find the number of elements in all three parts?

Comment: Start with Part 1.  Where does $p$ send $x=10$?  Repeat the mapping until the results return to $x=10$ and you will have mapped out its orbit.

Comment: Ok i got the following matrix $$\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&{10}&{11}\\
1&9&3&8&4&{10}&2&6&7&{11}&5
\end{array}} \right)$$ You mean $f(10) = 11$?

Comment: I'll take your word that is an equivalent way to represent the permutation $p$, but I like the disjoint cycle representation you originally had better for these kinds of problems.

Comment: Do you mean $10 \mapsto 11 \mapsto 5 \mapsto 4 \mapsto 8 \mapsto 6 \mapsto 10$ so the orbit is $\{ 10,11,5,4,8,6\} $ with 6 elements right?

Comment: Correct.  Notice that the disjoint cycles representation essentially shows us all the orbits, and in particular the set of size six that contains $x=10$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$G$ operates on $X$ by permutation. Hence $p\cdot 10=11$, $p^2\cdot 10= p\cdot 11=5$, &c. Thus $\;G\cdot 10=\{4,5,6,8,10,11\}$.

$G$ is a group of order $6$, since the disjoint cycles making up $p$ have order $3,6,1,1$. The orbit of $10$ has cardinal $6$, and we have a bijection from $G/G_{10}$ onto $G\cdot 10$, hence $ G_{10}=1$.

Comment: Two questions: 1) How did you find out that the order of group $G$ is $6$? 2) In your calculation of the $G/G_{10}$ how did you get $1$?

Comment: A cycle of length $r$ has order $r$, hence a product of disjoint cycles has order the l.c.m. of the lengths of the cycles. For $G_{10}=1$,we know $\lvert G\rvert=\lvert G/G_{10}\rvert \lvert G_{10}\rvert=\lvert G\cdot 10\rvert \lvert G_{10}\rvert$.

Comment: What Bernard is saying is that the only powers $k$ of $p$ that fix $x=10$ are those where $k$ is a multiple of six, and $p^6$ is the identity permutation.  So the second part, which subgroup of $G$ fixes $x=10$, is the trivial subgroup $\{e = p^0\} \subset G$.  Bernard did not spell out for you what group of order $6$ is $G$, but you can certainly compute the powers of $p$ up to the fifth power, and thus $G=\{p^0,p^1,p^2,\ldots,p^5\}$.